Two definition for "proper function"?
I see two different definitions for "proper function".   The first one is for convex functions.

A function f is proper if $f(x) < ∞$ for at least one $x \in X$.

A function between topological spaces is called proper if inverse images of compact subsets are compact.


What is a proper function?
Which one is more common that I shall follow? Are they similar for real convex functions?

Which one you should follow depends on the context. The first definition is typically used in convex optimization to simplify the statements of some theorems. The second is standard for topologists. Neither of these two groups will ever use the other definition because it is not relevant for their domain. This is simply the case of the same word being used for two different things in two different branches of mathematics.

@MichalAdamaszek The paper I am reading is in applied math&stats and the authors did not give a definition for proper functions...

Then you may have to guess it from the context of how it is being used. Although in this domain I would not expect 2 to be a thing...
